# Download tex source from wikipedia article

Tags: article

Like the question says, Is there any way to download a compilable tex source from a wikipedia article? Or maybe a tool that generates a tex source from a wikipedia article.

Comment: It's in fact to make `.pdf` versions of it or to export it to plain text (text, not tex!) using the Book Creator

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know that, but wiki's pdf rendering is not exactly the best. I'd prefer more customization

Comment: This isn't really a TeX question: it's about how you get the back-end used by Wikipedia to export as `.tex`. Not sure it's on-topic for us.

Comment: @Olayinka: Well, use the plain text download and edit the text ;-) The LaTeX export seems to be disable for a while already

Comment: @JosephWright Or "how to convert a `.wiki` file to a `.tex` file. But I'm not sure it makes the question more on-topic for us.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not to sound lazy, but that sounds like hard work. Wikipedia text uses MediaWiki tags and tex markup, a tool to generate tex sources isn't such a bad idea. Might be I'll look into it. There are some good parsers out there https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Benutzer:Dirk_Huenniger/wb2pdf

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks! I'll try that tool and give a feedback

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it, but `pandoc` (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc and http://pandoc.org/) can import MediaWiki format as used by Wikipedia and export different flavours of TeX including LaTeX.

Pandoc is free software, released under the GPL.